# QString& QString::operator=(const QByteArray&)' is private

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to read standard output from `QProcess` as `QString` where the passed argument is a linux command. The linux command gives me the linux username. When I pass the argument to `QProcess` I expect the output to be my linux username. In doing so I have to read the standard output and get the result as `QString` but I get the error:

```
QString& QString::operator=(const QByteArray&)' is private.
```

My code:

```
QProcess process;
process.start(QString::fromStdString("whoami"));
process.waitForFinished(-1); // will wait forever until finished
QByteArray name = process.readAllStandardOutput();
QString username = name;  //Error here saying
```

Comment: That's weird, [this reference](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html) says that the [`operator=(const QByteArray&)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#operator-eq-5) function is public. Are you doing something you do now show us? Can you please create a [Minimal, ***Complete***, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us?

Comment: Also, the error you show us doesn't actually match the code you show us. With `QString username = name` it would be a `public` [*constructor*](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#QString-8) of `QString` that should be used, not the assignment operator. Again, please show us a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and the actual errors (in full, complete, and without modifications).

Comment: username is a class variable declared as static QString username  in .h file. In the above code:-  username = name is used. Hence assignment operator is called.

Comment: Then please edit your question to show us a [Minimal, ***Complete***, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Don't just make up code. And when you edit your question then copy-paste (as text) the full output when building the MCVE into the question body as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
QProcess process;
process.start(QString::fromStdString("whoami"));
process.waitForFinished(-1); // this could be omitted
QTextStream txtStream(&process);
QString username = txtStream.readLine();
```

Note `QTextStream` by default is using default locale string encoding what is preferred. You can use `QTextStream::setCodec` to change string encoding (UTF-8, Windows-1250, UCS or whatever you need, default codec from system locale is usually best choice).
It also allows you to process data in streamed manner and this is always good.

Comment: You should explain what is different about your code and why. Otherwise readers have to play spot the difference.

Comment: first fo all my example complies :P.

Comment: Worked for me . Thanks :)

Comment: @Marek R . What if the QProcess fails and gives a standard Error. Will it work for this case as well? If it does then it will assign the error text to username isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Simply do this:

```
QByteArray name = process.readAllStandardOutput();
QString username = QString::fromRawData(name.data(), name.size());
```